# How to check MatOfKeyPoint in java?

Tags: java, opencv, mat

How to check if a MatOfKeyPoints is empty or not?

```
MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
```

What I need is something like

```
    if(matOfKeyPoint.size() != 1x0){
    //..............................
    }
```

The Error is as below:

```
Multiple markers a this line:
Syntax Error on token "x0",delete this token
Incompatible operand types size and int
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`1x0` is not a valid hex integer in Java. `matOfKeyPoint.size()` has return type of `Size`.

You should use:

```
if(matOfKeyPoint.empty())
```

Comment: or `if(!matOfKeyPoint.empty())`

Comment: if(matOfKeyPoint.size() != 0x0) is still incompatible

Comment: if(matOfKeyPoint.size() != 0) is incompatible as well

Comment: Looking at the Javadoc, size() returns a Size object, with a height, and a width.  Look at those values.  You can't compare an object reference to a primitive value in Java.

Comment: @JürgenK. check my answer again, please.